# Equals & hashcode in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, equals, hashcode

My question is why ArrayList does not remove duplicates even after I implement hashcode & equals in my custom object.

For eg: I have employee object with id & name as attribute, also I override hashcode & equals as below

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;

    if (this.id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where in the documentation of ArrayList did you read that it's a collection that removes duplicates? You're confusing it with HashSet. Note that returning a constant value in hashCode is a terrible idea.

Comment: None of the standard lists remove duplicates. You need to use a HashSet.

Comment: That I totally know that java docs does not say that lists are meant to remove duplicates but the reason we use equals & hashcode is to make sure that each object is identified as unique. I am also aware of set which does remove duplicates. But I wanted to understand the significance of equals & hashcode when using with arraylist. And no need to downvote if you don't understand questions fully

Answer (score 1):

Because `List`s can contain duplicate elements. If you don't want this, you would use `HashSet`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

`remove` removes only the first occurrence ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int))):

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present

If you want no duplicates in the first place - you can use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Comment: Actually, you can call `removeAll(Collections.singleton(element))` to remove all occurrences with writing a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Lists are not meant for unique values. This is clearly documented in `java.util.List`'s javadocs:

> Unlike sets, lists typically allow duplicate elements. More formally, lists typically allow pairs of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and they typically allow multiple null elements if they allow null elements at all. It is not inconceivable that someone might wish to implement a list that prohibits duplicates, by throwing runtime exceptions when the user attempts to insert them, but we expect this usage to be rare.

If you need a collection of unique values, use `Set` (you probably want to use `HashSet`)